# How to fix 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.hd$1()Ljava/lang/Object'

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, oozie

So I started to write up my own Oozie workflow that contains Apache Spark action and the thing is that even though I clearly sbt-packaged my source with Scala 2.11.8 and Spark 2.3.0, the yarn says

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.hd$1()Ljava/lang/Object;

There is a docker container containing Hortonworks HDP Sandbox running on ec2 machine with 16 cores cpu and 41 gigs of memory. I have already updated Oozie shared library using command line. Below are my job.properties file and workflow.xml file.

job.properties

```
jobTracker=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8032
master=yarn-cluster
oozie.action.sharelib.for.spark=spark2
oozie.action.sharelib.for.spark.exclusion=oozie/jackson
# Time and schedule details
start_date=2015-01-01T00:00Z
end_date=2015-06-30T00:00Z
frequency=55 23 L * ?
nameNode=hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020
# Workflow to run
wf_application_path=hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/hue/learn_oozie/ch08/spark_rainfall
# Coordinator to run
oozie.coord.application.path=hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/hue/learn_oozie/ch08/spark_rainfall
# Datasets
data_definitions=hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/hue/learn_oozie/ch08/datasets/datasets.xml
# Controls
timeout=10
concurrency_level=1
execution_order=FIFO
materialization_throttle=1
```

workflow.xml

```xml
<workflow-app name="ch08_spark_max_rainfall" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">

    <start to="max_rainfall"/>

    <action name="max_rainfall">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>${master}</master>
            <name>"Spark Ch08 Max Rain Calculator"</name>
            <class>life.jugnu.learnoozie.ch08.MaxRainfall</class>
            <jar>hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/hue/learn_oozie/ch08/rainbow/target/scala-2.11/rainbow_2.11-1.0.14.jar</jar>
            <spark-opts>
                --conf spark.yarn.historyServer.address=http://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:18088
                --conf spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory
                --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true
            </spark-opts>
            <arg>${input}</arg>
            <arg>${output}</arg>
        </spark>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>

    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>

    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

I expect this workflow run without any problem and write the result on the HDFS in remote cluster but the spark action got killed with error message below.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.hd$1()Ljava/lang/Object;
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMasterArguments.parseArgs(ApplicationMasterArguments.scala:45)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMasterArguments.(ApplicationMasterArguments.scala:34)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:576)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)

Comment: In my experience, getting Spark actions to work in Oozie is a debugging exercise. I would start by setting oozie.use.system.libpath=true in your properties, and set oozie.libpath if your sharelib path is non-default (default is something like /user/oozie/share/lib/)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. It was because we were using version 4.1.0 of Oozie on our cluster. Spark actions are only available 4.2.0+.